# Boost.Asio thread safety

Tags: boost-asio

Is it safe to call async_write & async_read from different threads in situation when io_service::run() was called from only one thread?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to call `async_write` & `async_read` from different threads

Yes, but with a caveat. You can safely do this for distinct `socket` [objects](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html)

> *Thread Safety*
>
> Distinct objects: **Safe**.
>
> Shared objects: **Unsafe**.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is conservative on that and says "no".

But I'm doing this anyway in one of my linux programs and it seems to work fine.  Digging into boost/asio/detail/epoll_reactor.ipp shows that the function start_op() is indeed protected by a mutex, so my confidence is increased.

But other platforms may be different..

Comment: Access to shared objects is not safe.
See: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/10009