# Boost asio multithreading

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boost.Asio thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639349/boost-asio-thread-safety)

Is

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
```

thread safe?

I mean, can I call the methods of a shared tcp::socket (socket.connect(), read_some(), close()) from different threads without worrying about race condition issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Boost 1.52, it is not thread safe.

This is documented in the "Thread Safety" section [in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html):

*Thread Safety*

**Distinct objects:** Safe.

**Shared objects:** Unsafe.